# MySQL database manipulation program for Windows? Like MS Access or MS SQL?

Tags: mysql, windows, user-interface

Is there any program (preferably official) for Windows that can be used to manipulate MySQL data dumps?

For example, easily importing a MySQL text dump and create the database for all kinds of manipulations (you know, common data operations such as select, update, insert, delete, export into CSV, etc.) via a GUI interface. Much like what you can do with MS Excel and MS Access.

I know only phpMyAdmin which requires a local web server environment which might a little too much for what I need.

I thought http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ was what I needed and installed to find out that it's not.

Any such tools exist? I ask this is actually because **these MySQL dumps are for my users who know nothing about SQL or anything technical**. This is for them, not me. After they downloaded the SQL I provided, they ask me: "How can I open it?"

I tried to provide them CSV, but CSV generated by this approach: http://www.kavoir.com/2010/11/mysql-export-table-to-csv-text-files-for-excel.html would contain stuff like **\"** if the original data contains **"**. When you open the CSV in Excel, **\"** are all over the place.

Comment: You could just set up an ODBC source with the MySQL connector and use Access. Wouldn't be quite the same as a native tool, but would handle most things you throw at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webyog.com/en/

I used to use SQLyog at my last job. It's a pretty decent GUI tool for interacting with MySQL, either local or remote. It'll cost you $99 at the cheapest, but you can try it for 30 days. If you like it and it makes life easier, it could be worth the $99, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Running a local server is actually pretty easy.  I use [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) which was really easy to install and came set up and ready to use phpMyAdmin.  It's also really easy to shut the whole server (or just parts of it) down when it's not in use to conserve system resources.